# CUPS session setup failed with 'nt_status_logon_failure'

Tags: linux, windows, printing, cups

I am running the CUPS in Linux Debian machine. Using the CUPS I am sending the print request to Windows XP machine. I have enabled the 445 and 139 port and I am able to connect the Windows Machine. Printer is connected to the Windows Machine.

I am sending the print request using the following command

```
lp -E -d < Printer Name > file name.
```

After sending I am checking the printer status using the following command

```
lpstat -p < Printer Name >
```

I am getting the below error message when I execute the above message.

```
unable to connect to cifs host will retry in 60 seconds..
```

When I checked in the log I am getting the below error message.

```
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE  and NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

The DeviceURI is like below in /etc/cups/printers.conf

```
 smb://username:password@IP Address of windows Machine/printer_Name
```

Please let me know if the password is having '@' symbol, how can we specify the '@' with actual syntax in DeviceURI ( **user:password@IP** )

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you provide not enough detailed info about your specific setup. So I will make an effort to take several potential problems into account and give hints how to overcome them:

## I.

Did you use the ***correct share name*** for your shared Windows printer?

To find out, use this command:

```
$ smbtree -U windowsusername
```

You might see something like the following output:

```
WORKGROUP
   \\MURUGA-PC
      \\MURUGA-PC\G
      \\MURUGA-PC\Z
      \\MURUGA-PC\Public
      \\MURUGA-PC\print$                      Printer Drivers
      \\MURUGA-PC\EPSON Stylus CX8400 Series  EPSON Stylus CX8400 Series
```

In other words: your printer's share name may contain spaces. But you cannot use spaces in the device URI for CUPS! What now?

Easy: (1) Either rename the share name on the Windows side. (2) Or escape the space by using `%20` instead:

```
smb://muruga:mysecretpassword@muruga-pc/EPSON%20Stylus%20CX8400%20Serie
```

---

## II.

Is your Windows XP by any chance using ***Kerberos authentication?*** For example, because it is part of an *Active Directory* environment? Then you should refer to this document on cups.org:

- [Configuring CUPS to Use Kerberos](https://www.cups.org/doc/kerberos.html)

Kerberos authentication does not work with username/password, it uses 'tickets'.

---

## III.

Otherwise, if your Windows XP machine is part of a "standard" domain, you may be more successful by ditching your device URI of <strike>`smb://username:password@ip-address-of-windows/printer_name`</strike> and use this instead:

```
smb://username:password@domain_name/windows_host/printer_Name
```

The *username* you use has to be the Windows user name (with his/her password) who installed the printer on Windows!

---

## IV.

Alternatively, you may have success by using IPP to print to Windows (though XP needs an IPP-enabling extension installed, provided by Microsoft). Be aware that MS is using a non-standard syntax for their device URIs (using port 80 or 443), and their version of IPP is still 1.0 (which always remained in "draft" status and never made it into an official release by the IETF):

```
DeviceURI https://mywindowsprintserver/printers/printername/.printer
```

or

```
DeviceURI http://mywindowsprintserver/printers/printername/.printer
```

For username/password authentication to this printer, you need

1. *`AuthInfoRequired  username,password`* in `/etc/cups/printers.conf` and
2. *`DefaultAuthType Basic`* in `cupsd.conf`.

To use Kerberos, you need

1. *`AuthInfoRequired Negotiate`* in `/etc/cups/printers.conf` and
2. *`DefaultAuthType Negotiate`* in `cupsd.conf`.

---

If the whole setup is in a household with a private LAN/WLAN, you may want to consider removing all access controls (first on the Windows print server side, then):

1. *`AuthInfoRequired None`* in `/etc/cups/printers.conf` and
2. *`DefaultAuthType None`* in `cupsd.conf`.

---

If your problem is that your password contains a `'@'`-character, then try this:

```
smb://username:'p@ssword'@domain_name/windows_host/printer_Name
```

or

```
smb://username:p%40ssword@domain_name/windows_host/printer_Name
```